# AttributeError in scikit-posthocs: 'module' object has no attribute 'critical_difference_diagram

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot the critical difference diagram using the scikit-learn API, but I'm encountering the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'scikit_posthocs' has no attribute 'critical_difference_diagram'

Here is a snippet of my code for a better understanding of my question:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
import scikit_posthocs as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Example of used data
data = [...]
data1 = np.array([data])

#Call the Nemenyi posthoc test
result = sp.posthoc_nemenyi_friedman(data1.T)

#Plot the result
sp.sign_plot(result)

#Here I'm trying to plot the CD diagram, but a warning/error message appears.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 2), dpi=100)
plt.title('Critical difference diagram of average score ranks')
sp.critical_difference_diagram(data1, result)
```

Please, can you help me identify and correct the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I write 0.7.0 is the current version of scikit_posthocs on https://pypi.org/project/scikit-posthocs/#history . There is no `critical_difference_diagram` in version 0.7.0. You need to install it via git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/maximtrp/scikit-posthocs.git
```

Also, critical_difference_diagram first parameter is a rank list and not the data itself. Here an example using meanrank as rank to `critical_difference_diagram`:

```
import scikit_posthocs as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Example of used data
x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
z = [3, 1, 10, 12, 13]

data = np.array([x, y, z]).T

# Calculate meanrank
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
rankmat = df.rank(axis='columns', ascending=True)
meanranks = rankmat.mean()

#Call the Nemenyi posthoc test
result = sp.posthoc_nemenyi_friedman(data)

#Plot the result
sp.sign_plot(result)

#Here I'm trying to plot the CD diagram, but a warning/error message appears.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 2), dpi=100)
plt.title('Critical difference diagram of average score ranks')
sp.critical_difference_diagram(meanranks.to_list(), result)

plt.show()
```